# Gamma Incomplete Function representation in Mathematica and Matlab

Tags: special-functions

I am confused about incomplete gamma function calculation in *Mathematica* and MATLAB:

For example, in *Mathematica*:
`Gamma[5,3] = 19.56`

But in MATLAB:
`gammainc(5,3) = 0.8753`

I don't know which one is correct, MATLAB result or *Mathematica* result?

Comment: Also, this relationship is valid: gammainc(a,b,'upper')*gamma(b) in Matlab gives the same result as Gamma[b,a] in Mathematica.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In *Mathematica*, `Gamma[a, z]` refers to the upper incomplete Gamma function, given by

$$\Gamma(a,z)=\int_z^\infty t^{a-1}e^{-t}\,dt$$

whereas in MATLAB, `gammainc(z, a)` refers to the regularized lower incomplete Gamma function

$$P(a,z)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(a)}\int_0^z t^{a-1}e^{-t}\, dt$$

Obviously, they give different results. To get MATLAB's result in *Mathematica*, use the following:

```
gammainc[a_, z_] := Gamma[a, 0, z]/Gamma[a]
N@gammainc[3, 5]

(* 0.875348 *)
```

Comment: In fact, you could simplify things slightly: `gammainc[a_, z_] := GammaRegularized[a, 0, z]`; it has been anticipated that people would frequently want the scaled version.