# PDF for Gamma Distribution not what I expect

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I have plotted the the PDF for a Gamma Distribution with various parameters (e.g. 3 and 5) using `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[PDF[GammaDistribution[α, β], x], {x, -1, 20}], 
  { α, -1, 8}, { β, -1, 6}]
```

However, the plots that I get are quite different to what I get using R and which I know to be correct. For example the `PDF` with $\Gamma(3,5)$ should have a peak in the curve at 0.4. The plot that *Mathematica* produces gives me a peak that is more like `11`.

Does anybody have any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Any reason why you are not using the built-in `GammaDistribution` ?

Comment: You're using a shape/scale parametrization (and getting the correct result). Most likely R is using a shape/rate parametrization. Try `alpha = 3, beta = 1/5` to get the PDF you are looking for.

Comment: As Simon said, you should verify R's implementations of Gamma and make sure that the arguments are same. [There's](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/34631/5) an example where the implementation differed between MATLAB and _Mathematica_, so it's not uncommon.

Comment: Are you by any chance the same person who asked [this](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/202481?p_p_auth=Gfo6HIdu) question?  If not, take a look at the answers there.

Answer (score 4):

In Mathematica, the PDF of a `GammaDistribution[a,b]` is proportional to 
$$x^{a-1} e^{-\frac{x}{b}},$$ as described in the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GammaDistribution.html).

In R, `dgamma(x, shape=a, rate=r)` is a PDF proportional to

$$x^{a-1} e^{-r x},$$

again as described in the [documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/GammaDist.html).

R's rate $r$ is the same as Mathematica's $1/b$.  Just make sure you use these parameters correctly.  Or use the `scale` parameter of R, as in `dgamma(x, shape=a, scale=b)`.

For many such functions there's no universal agreement on what is the meaning of the first, second, etc. parameters.  Always be sure to look up the notational conventions used by the book you are reading or the software you are using.