# Is there an equivalent of “pmtm” of MATLAB?

Tags: signal-processing, matlab

Recently I'm spending my time implementing some patients' analysis using Mathematica `Classify` function. But I need to rewrite some MATLAB functions for computing input parameters.

There is a problem, that I haven't found an alternative for `pmtm` function.

**In short:**
Is there any way how to rewrite this code in Mathematica?

```
[p,f] = pmtm(data,tapers,n,fs);
```

Where data is a column vector with 2048 elements, fs = 40, tapers = 8 and n = 2^nextpow2(size(data,1)) = 2048;

**Edit:**
1. Link to `pmtm` function is http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/pmtm.html
2. `[pxx,f] = pmtm(x,nw,f,fs) returns the two-sided multitaper PSD estimates at the frequencies specified in the vector, f. The vector, f, must contain at least 2 elements. The frequencies in f are in cycles per unit time. The sampling frequency, fs, is the number of samples per unit time. If the unit of time is seconds, then f is in cycles/sec (Hz).`

Comment: If you use [MATLink](http://matlink.org), then it is as simple as `pmtm = MFunction["pmtm", "OutputArguments" -> 2]` after you initialize the package. You'd call it as `{p, f} = pmtm[data, tapers, n, fs]`.

Comment: Now I'm using MATLink, but I need to convert it to C++ / C# .dll in another phase of my project. And MATLAB Coder doesn't support `pmtm` function, but inMathematica I can use `CCodeGeneration`.

Comment: We can't help with C++/C# conversion either. You can look at the source code by typing `edit pmtm`. That should give you hints to proceed with your translation attempts.

Comment: Mathematica code will not be per se easily convertible to C,  only a very limited function subset will support direct compilation.

Comment: @OleksandrR. To me it looks like the OP just asks wether there is a simple equivalent of this function in Mathematica. We have had and answered questions like that before.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries yes, you could be right. I didn't read it that way, but it is a plausible interpretation. I retract my close vote.

Comment: Related: [(55555)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55555/121)